# Exempt shadow from screen blending

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swiftui

Trying to use a View.shadow(...) function in SwiftUI to create a glow effect around an object in concert with the View.blend(.screen).

When I layer the objects without the shadow, they are the proper colors and blend properly:

[image: Desired colors]

When I add the shadow, each object's shadow seems to blend with the object itself, shifting the colors:

[image: Shadow blended colors]

Is there any way to have the shadow not blend with it's associated object?

Code snippit:

```
Path(path1)
    .foregroundColor(Color(color1))
    .shadow(color: Color(color1), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 0)
    .blendMode(.screen)
Path(path2)
    .foregroundColor(Color(color2))
    .shadow(color: Color(color2), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 0)
    .blendMode(.screen)
```

Comment: I assume (as provided code not enough to test) that the issue is due to order of applied modifiers. Try to detach `.shadow` from paths, wrap paths into container (if they are not yet), and apply `.shadow` to that container. So blending would apply directly to paths, and shadow will be applied only to result.

Comment: Paths are in ZStack container. Realized and corrected a mistake in my example code: I'm using the shadows to create a glow effect on each Path, so each Path's shadow must match its color and blend with the other Paths.